# Is possible to print a ftable with tableGrob in RStudio?

Tags: r, datatable, datagridtablestyle

I would like to print this ftable with tableGrob.

```
tab=ftable(data, row.vars = c("Sales.Year","Return"),col.vars="Category")
```

And i'd also like to add margins.
How can i do?

Comment: Hi Marco, good first question, but I think it needs some more details:
1) can you format your code with the backticks like in markdown? (think RNotebook code chunks)
2) What is data? Can you make a _reproducible_ example we can understand with something like `iris` which is a data set built into R
3) can you explain more about why you want to print with `tableGrob`? `ftable` already has a print method (as seen here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/ftable)

Comment: Hi, i've used tableGrob to print a several number of table yet, so i'd like to continue with this method.

tab=ftable(data, row.vars = c("Sales.Year","Return"),col.vars="Category")

Return is a dicotomic variable with value 0 and 1.
Category is a categorical variable.

I don't know how to insert the table that I'd want as an example.

Comment: Category     0   OTH   PFA   PFD   PFF   PFM   PFS   PFT
Sales.Year Authorized.to.return                                                         
2015       0                                28     9 10337    39   132 41800  1111     0
           1                                 0     0   599     0    24   867   186     0
2016       0                                 0     3 11372    44   245 45000  2631     0
           1                                 0     0   464     0    66   590   153     0

Comment: Ok, but I don't think you need `tableGrob` here, so you are making life more difficult for yourself. when you say "print" do you mean to the R session as text, or somewhere else? Also, please _edit_ your answer with the changes, and delete the comments, then we can keep things tidy and clear :)